# Android: How make this kind of popup menu?

Tags: android, checkbox, popupmenu

A fairly simple question, I believe.

On my Android phone (running Android 2.3.3) I occasionally run into popup-menus that I quite like. They're not context menus, nor option menus -- at least, I believe they aren't.

An example: if you have Skype installed, and you try to call a contact, a popup-menu will ask you whether you want to use the dialer or Skype to complete this action. When it shows up, it greys out the current activity without closing it or opening a new activity.

Does anybody know what this kind of menu is called, and how I create it?

More precisely, I want this menu to show up when the user enables a certain Checkbox in my application.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Though, I dint see this notice in Skype, but are you talking about Popup Window something like this : http://www.edumobile.org/android/android-apps/quick-action-demo/

Comment: They are called Dialog

Comment: see [this](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-alert-dialog-example/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what your talking about is a custom dialog box? Tell me if that's wrong. BUT here are some links to get you started if what you want is a custom dialog box

[Android - Activity that does not fill the parent screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1903590/android-activity-that-does-not-fill-the-parent-screen)

http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/how-display-custom-dialog-your-android-application

Comment: That seems to be what I was looking for! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

that is the action menu that comes up when you sent an intent to do something ie. bring up the dialer. if there is more than one option that does the same thing you will be presented with this dialog to choose what you want to do.

this is also seen when you want to share a picture or something

[image]

If you have a third party launcher and press the home button you will also see this so that the OS knows what application you want to use to show the home screen.

Basically its a custom dialog